# Tough recursive task

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I've been struggle with question I'm trying to solve as part of test preparation, and I thought I could use your help.
I need to write a Boolean method that takes array with integers (positive and negative), and return true if the array can be split to two **equals** groups, that the amount of every group's numbers is equals to the other group.
For exmaple, for this array:

```
int[]arr = {-3, 5, 12, 14, -9, 13};
```

The method will return true, since -3 + 5 + 14 = 12 + -9 + 13.

For this array:

```
int[]arr = {-3, 5, -12, 14, -9, 13};
```

The method will return false since even though -3 + 5 + 14 + -12 = -9 + 13, the amount of numbers in every side of the equation isn't equals.

For the array:

```
int[]arr = {-3, 5, -12, 14, -9};
```

The method will return false since array length isn't even.

The method **must** be recursive, overloading is allowed, every assist method must be recursive too, and I don't need to worry about complexity.

I've been trying to solve this for three hours, I don't even have a code to show since all the things I did was far from the solution.

If someone can at least give me some pseudo code it will be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is a mistake in youe example - do you mean `5` instead of `15` in the first definition of `arr`?

Comment: Just a hint: If the cross sum of all digits isn't dividible by 2, there is no way to divide the array into 2 groups, when **all** numbers are **positive**.
I.e. 1+2+3+4+5+6 has 21 as its cross sum so you cant split it into 2 groups. But 1,2,3,4,5,7 has 22 which would be 2+4+5 = 1+3+7. So as a first step you could test if all the numbers are positive and if so check the cross sum. (I am not sure if this is a smart way to do so, maybe the recursion would solve it in a better way, shot from the hip).

Comment: Is there any requirement for this to run in O(whatever) or does it just have to  work and be recursive?

Comment: Oh and how long are the arrays at maximum? Because brute forcing and testing every combination might take very long.

Comment: You can solve it by brute force simply by saying that each number must either be on the left or the right of the equation; keep a sum and a count of the numbers on each side of the equation, and update either the "left" or "right" pair of numbers at each step in the recursion. It's O(2^n), but that's small for the inputs you've given.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. The question didn't mention anything about the array length,but let's start by solving it only for the example. And don't need to worry about complexity (There is another question that deals with complexity in the exam, even harder, but let's leave it to another day:))

Comment: Now that I think about it: The cross product will show you, if the array is dividble into 2 groups regardless of the sign! The first array you have given has 32 as its cross sum -> there is a solution. The second array you have given has -5 as its cross sum -> uneven -> no solution possible.

Comment: @hamena314 what is the "cross sum"?

Comment: @AndyTurner: Sorry, not a native english speaker. In german it's called "Quersumme", which is the sum of all elements of a row / array. "cross total, digit sum, crossfoot" seem to be other translations.

Comment: @hamena314 I'd just call that the "sum" :) You also mention cross product, though.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Cross product definitely was wrong! But the "cross sum" in german usually get's used to sum up the digits of a number i.e. a zip code is 94532 ... then the cross sum is 9+4+5+3+2 = 23. The "sum of some numbers" means that there are single numbers that you add up. So "cross sum" is more like the sum of digits of a number while a "sum" is a sum of single numbers. But as both concepts are very similar and do the same it seems more or less my explanation should be "because there is a word in german for it". :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for pseudocode, but sometimes it's just as easy and clear to write it as Java.

The general idea of this solution is to try adding each number to either the left or the right of the equation. It keeps track of the count and sum on each side at each step in the recursion. More explanation in comments:

```
class Balance {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(balanced(-3, 5, 12, 14, -9, 13));   // true
    System.out.println(balanced(-3, 5, -12, 14, -9, 13));  // false
  }

  private static boolean balanced(int... nums) {
    // First check if there are an even number of nums.
    return nums.length % 2 == 0
        // Now start the recursion:
        && balanced(
            0, 0,  // Zero numbers on the left, summing to zero.
            0, 0,  // Zero numbers on the right, summing to zero.
            nums);
  }

  private static boolean balanced(
      int leftCount, int leftSum,
      int rightCount, int rightSum,
      int[] nums) {
    int idx = leftCount + rightCount;
    if (idx == nums.length) {
      // We have attributed all numbers to either side of the equation.
      // Now check if there are an equal number and equal sum on the two sides.
      return leftCount == rightCount && leftSum == rightSum;
    } else {
      // We still have numbers to allocate to one side or the other.
      return
          // What if I were to place nums[idx] on the left of the equation?
          balanced(
              leftCount + 1, leftSum + nums[idx],
              rightCount, rightSum,
              nums)
          // What if I were to place nums[idx] on the right of the equation?
          || balanced(
              leftCount, leftSum,
              rightCount + 1, rightSum + nums[idx],
              nums);
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a first idea solution. It's O(2^n), which is obviously rather slow for large `n`, but it's fine for the size of problems you have given as examples.

Comment: This code is f**king perfect, no even need to use assist method, and it so clean and short. man your my hero

Comment: Can you please give me some tips of how to solve this kind of questions in the future? What's the process? you start by thinking about the base case? about what's the big problem, and how to make it small by steps? recursive can be so hard when you try to master it.@AndyTurner

Comment: That's a pretty broad question to answer; mostly, it just takes familiarity and practice (I'm certainly not going to claim some deep CS knowledge...). Think about how you can break down the larger problem into a smaller problem (e.g. instead of how to bipartition N numbers, how do you assign 1 number to one of the partitions); and what do you need to know about the solution to the smaller problem in order to solve the rest of the problem (e.g. the sum/count of numbers in the two partitions so far).

Comment: @Andy Turner, Respected Mr. Turner, How will we know when the first command-recursion ```balanced(leftCount + 1, leftSum + nums[idx], rightCount, rightSum, nums)``` will be performed and when the second command-recursion ```balanced(leftCount, leftSum, rightCount + 1, rightSum + nums[idx], nums)``` will be performed? Explain, please.

Answer (score 4):

The problem described is a version of the [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem. First note that your formulation is equivalent to deciding whether there is a subset of the input which sums up to half of the sum of all elements (which is required to be an integral number, otherwise the instance cannot be solved, but this is easy to check). Basically, in each recursive step, it is to be decided whether the first number is to be selected into the subset or not, resulting in different recursive calls. If `n` denotes the number of elements, there must be `n/2` (which is required to be integral again) items selected.

Let `Sum` denote the sum of the input and let `Target := Sum / 2` which in the sequel is assumed to be integral. if we let

```
f(arr,a,count) := true
                  if there is a subset of arr summing up to a with
                  exactly count elements
                  false
                  otherwise
```

we obtain the following recursion

```
f(arr,a,count) = (arr[0] == a && count == 1)
                 ||
                 (a == 0 && count == 0)
                 if arr contains only one element
                 f(arr\arr[0], a, count)
                 ||
                 f(arr\arr[0], a - arr[0], count -1)
                 if arr contains more than one element
```

where `||` denotes logical disjuction, `&&` denoted logical conjunction and `\` denotes removal of an element.
The two cases for a non-singleton array correspond to chosing the first element of `arr` into the desired subset or its relative complement. Note that in an actual implementation, `a` would not be actually removed from the array; a starting index, which is used as an additional argument, would be initialized with `0` and increased in each recursive call, eventually reaching the end of the array.

Finally, `f(arr,Target,n/2)` yields the desired value.

Comment: Does this take into account the balancing requirement?

Comment: Oh my, it doesn't! I misread that part of the question. This can be taken care of with an additional argument.

Comment: Note that the balancing can also be enforced by fiddling with the instance: Select a posive `M` which is larger than the absolute value of `Sum`; add this to the entries, which also eliminates zero entries in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy for this should be to try all combinations possible. I will try to document how I would go about to get to this.

NOTE that I think the requirement: make every function use recursion is a bit hard, because I would solve that by leaving out some helper functions that make the code much more readable, so in this case I wont do it like that.

With recursion you always want to make progression towards a final solution, and detect when you are done.  So we need two parts in our function:

1. The recursive step: for which we will take the first element of the input set, and try what happens if we add it to the first set, and if that doesn't find a solution we'll try what happens when we add it to the second set.
2. Detect when we are done, that is when the input set is empty, in that case we either have found a solution or we have not.

A trick in our first step is that after taking the first element of our set, if we try to partition the remainder, we don't want the 2 sets being equal anymore, because we already assigned the first element to one of the sets.

This leads to a solution that follows this strategy:

```
public boolean isValidSet(MySet<int> inputSet, int sizeDifferenceSet1minus2)
{
    if (inputSet.isEmpty())
    {
         return sizeDifferenceSet1minus2== 0;
    }

    int first = inptuSet.takeFirst();
    return isValidSet(inputSet.copyMinusFirst(), sizeDifferenceSet1minus2+ first)
              || isValidSet(inputSet.copyMinusFirst(), sizeDifferenceSet1minus2+ -1 * first);
}
```

This code requires some help functions that you will still need to implement.

What it does is first test if we have reached the end condition, and if so returns if this partition is successful. If we still have elements left in the set, we try what happens if we add it to the first set and then what happens when adding it to the second set. Note that we don't actually keep track of the sets, we just keep track of the size difference between set 1 minus 2, decreasing the  (but instead you could pass along both sets).

Also note that for this implementation to work, you need to make copies of the input set and not modify it!

For some background information: This problem is called the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is famous for being NP-complete (which means it probably is not possible to solve it efficiently for large amounts of input data, but it is very easy to verify that a partitioning is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a verbose example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(balancedPartition(new int[] {-3, 5, 12, 14, -9, 13})); // true
    System.out.println(balancedPartition(new int[] {-3, 5, -12, 14, -9, 13})); // false
    System.out.println(balancedPartition(new int[] {-3, 5, -12, 14, -9})); // false
}

public static boolean balancedPartition(int[] arr)
{
    return balancedPartition(arr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", "");
}

private static boolean balancedPartition(int[] arr, int i, int groupA, int groupB, int counterA, int counterB, String groupAStr, String groupBStr)
{
    if (groupA == groupB && counterA == counterB && i == arr.length) // in case the groups are equal (also in the amount of numbers)
    {
        System.out.println(groupAStr.substring(0, groupAStr.length() - 3) + " = " + groupBStr.substring(0, groupBStr.length() - 3)); // print the groups
        return true;
    }
    
    if (i == arr.length) // boundaries checks
        return false;
    
    boolean r1 = balancedPartition(arr, i + 1, groupA + arr[i], groupB, counterA + 1, counterB, groupAStr + arr[i] + " + ", groupBStr); // try add to group 1
    boolean r2 = balancedPartition(arr, i + 1, groupA, groupB + arr[i], counterA, counterB + 1, groupAStr, groupBStr + arr[i] + " + "); // try add to group 2
    
    return r1 || r2;
}
```

Output:

-3 + 5 + 14 = 12 + -9 + 13 // one option for the first array

12 + -9 + 13 = -3 + 5 + 14 // another option for the first array

true // for the first array

false // for the second array

false // for the third array

Comment: This might be a fine solution, but its hard to read because of the exceptional line length.